# PyTorch not being able to use CUDA for some reason

Tags: python, yolov5

I want to use CUDA in PyTorch and torch.cuda.is_available() returns false.
All of my installed stuff:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: All of your cuda env variables set ?

Comment: do you have a GPU?  Do you have a new enough driver installed for your GPU?  Is the pytorch expecting CUDA 11.3?  have you [installed](https://pytorch.org/) `cudatoolkit=11.3` ?